# Expected number of successes when sampling N times from a binomial distribution, stopping after M successes?

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value, binomial-distribution, sampling

I'm trying to figure out the equation for the expected number of successes $E(X)$ when sampling from a binomial distribution with success probability $p$. In this sampling scheme, we either sample $N$ times, or until we observe $M$ successes, whichever comes first.

For example, if $N = 10$ and $M = 3$, the results might look like

| # | Run 1 | Run 2 | Run 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T (1 success) | F | F |
| 2 | F | F | T (1 success) |
| 3 | T (2 successes) | T (1 success) | T (2 successes) |
| 4 | F | F | F |
| 5 | F | F | T (3 successes) |
| 6 | F | F | (stop) |
| 7 | T (3 successes) | T (2 successes) |  |
| 8 | (stop) | F |  |
| 9 |  | F |  |
| 10 |  | F |  |
| **Total Successes** | **3** | **2** | **3** |

I know that if the sampling scheme were only sampling $N$ times, then $E(X) = N p$. Similarly, if the sampling scheme was sampling until $M$ successes, naturally $E(X) = M$. However I'm having difficulty figuring out what the combination of the two stopping criteria would make $E(X)$.

Comment: You calculate the probability of seeing $0,1,2,3,\ldots M$ successes and use that to compute the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

If $M \geq N$, then the experiment will never reach $M$ successes *before* there are $N$ trials, so the expected value would be $N p$. The case where $M < N$ is less trivial.

Assuming $M < N$, you can separate the probabilities in the sum for the expected value $$E(X) = \sum_{k = 0}^M k P(\text{there are $k$ successes})$$ based on whether the experiment reaches $N$ trials or not.

If the experiment reaches $N$ trials, then the probability of $k$ successes is the usual binomial distribution calculation of $$\binom{N}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{N - k}.$$

If the experiment does not reach $N$ trials, then there must have been $M$ successes, *and* the $M$-th success appears before the $N$-th trial. Summing these probabilities based on *where* the $M$-th success appears, we get $$\sum_{k = M}^{N - 1} \binom{k}{M}p^M (1 - p)^{k - M}.$$

We can put these two observations together to express the expected value as $$E(X) = \sum_{k = 0}^M k \binom{N}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{N - k} + M \sum_{k = M}^{N - 1} \binom{k}{M} p^M (1 - p)^{k - M}.$$ The first sum can be rewritten as $$N p \sum_{k = 0}^{M - 1} \binom{N - 1}{k} p^k (1 - p)^{N - k - 1}$$ using the same technique one does to prove that the expected value of the binomial distribution is $N p$; but other than that, there probably isn’t a nicer way to express these partial sums of a binomial expansion.